# running regex query with mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I am running this regex: 
`^https?:\/\/www\.chkhikvadze\.com\/[a-z0-9-/]+-[0-9]\.[0-9]{7}$`
and getting this error: `My sql error 1139 invalid character name`.

when i remove this fragment `[a-z0-9-/]` or only `-/` it works. how can i fix it?

Comment: Try `^https?://www[.]chkhikvadze[.]com/[a-z0-9/-]+-[0-9][.][0-9]{7}$`

Comment: escape the "-", "/" and ".":  ^https?:\/\/www\.chkhikvadze\.com\/[a-z0-9\-\/]+\-[0-9]\.[0-9]{7}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the dash in front:

```
^https?:\/\/www\.chkhikvadze\.com\/[-a-z0-9/]+-[0-9]\.[0-9]{7}$
```

The parser thinks that `9-/` is supposed to be a range like `a-z`, but complains that it's not valid.